# Get the string up to a specific character

Tags: swift, string, character

```
var hello = "hello, how are you?"

var hello2 = "hello, how are you @tom?"
```

i want to delete every letter behind the @ sign.

result should be

```
var hello2 = "hello, how are you @tom?"
->
hello2.trimmed() 

print(hello2.trimmed())

-> "hello, how are you"
```

**Update**
As i want to use it to link multiple users and replace the space behind @sign with the correct name, I always need the reference to the latest occurrence of the @sign to replace it.

```
text3 = "hey i love you @Tom @Marcus @Peter"
```

Example what the final version should look like

to start off

var text = "hello @tom @mark @mathias"

i want to always get the index of the latest @ sign in the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @appzYourLife answer, the following will also trim off the whitespace characters after removing everything after the @ symbol.

```
import Foundation

var str = "hello, how are you @tom"

if str.contains("@") {
    let endIndex = str.range(of: "@")!.lowerBound
    str = str.substring(to: endIndex).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
}
print(str) // Output - "hello, how are you"
```

**UPDATE:**

In response to finding the last occurance of the `@` symbol in the string and removing it, here is how I would approach it:

```
var str = "hello, how are you @tom @tim?"
if str.contains("@") {
    //Reverse the string
    var reversedStr = String(str.characters.reversed())
    //Find the first (last) occurance of @
    let endIndex = reversedStr.range(of: "@")!.upperBound
    //Get the string up to and after the @ symbol
    let newStr = reversedStr.substring(from: endIndex).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    //Store the new string over the original
    str = String(newStr.characters.reversed())
    //str = "hello, how are you @tom"
}
```

Or looking at @appzYourLife answer use `range(of:options:range:locale:)` instead of literally reversing the characters

```
var str = "hello, how are you @tom @tim?"
if str.contains("@") {
    //Find the last occurrence of @
    let endIndex = str.range(of: "@", options: .backwards, range: nil, locale: nil)!.lowerBound
    //Get the string up to and after the @ symbol
    let newStr = str.substring(from: endIndex).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    //Store the new string over the original
    str = newStr
    //str = "hello, how are you @tom"
}
```

As an added bonus, here is how I would approach removing every `@` starting with the last and working forward:

```
var str = "hello, how are you @tom and @tim?"
if str.contains("@") {

    while str.contains("@") {
        //Reverse the string
        var reversedStr = String(str.characters.reversed())
        //Find the first (last) occurance of @
        let endIndex = reversedStr.range(of: "@")!.upperBound
        //Get the string up to and after the @ symbol
        let newStr = reversedStr.substring(from: endIndex).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

        //Store the new string over the original
        str = String(newStr.characters.reversed())
    }
    //after while loop, str = "hello, how are you"
}
```

Comment: This only works in case there is one @ sign, it would be more helpful if it detects the latest @ sign in the textfield :)

Comment: This answer was given before the original question was changed to involve multiple `@` symbols.

Comment: Yeah sorry, is there a solution to finding the latest occurrence of the @ sign?

Comment: @Zash__ I have updated my answer to include removing characters starting at the last `@` sign and also removing character starting from the first `@` working backward.

Comment: This does not solve my problem as I only want to replace the string behind the latest @ sign with the cell.nameLabel. When I write @ to and press on the cell with he label tomas it should change the text to @ tomas. And then I should be able to continue and link more users @ lo and press on the cell with the name Lola it should be @ lola -> "@ tomas @ lola".  (without the space but I can't send it without space between @ sign and username somehow here on stack)

Comment: I Used your second example and this prints out "@tim" instead of the "hello, how are you @ tom"

Comment: well, I played a bit around and found your first answer the closest, I approved it it is working how I imagined it :)

Comment: Happy that one of the code snippets was useful. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the range of the "@" and then use it to create a substring up to the index before.

```
import Foundation

let text = "hello, how are you @tom?"

if let range = text.range(of: "@") {
    let result = text.substring(to: range.lowerBound)
    print(result) // "hello, how are you "
}
```

### Considerations

> Please note that, following the logic you described and using the input text you provided, the output string will have a blank space as last character
>
> Also note that if multiple `@` are presente in the input text, then the first occurrence will be used.

---

### Last index [Update]

I am adding this new section to answer the question you posted in the comments.

If you have a text like this

```
let text = "hello @tom @mark @mathias"
```

and you want the index of the **last** occurrency of `"@"` you can write

```
if let index = text.range(of: "@", options: .backwards)?.lowerBound {
    print(index)    
}
```

Comment: thanks i will try it as soon as i am back at my project, makes sense and the empty space is good, thanks :)

Comment: i use this to link users, so if i want to link multiple, does this work? I will implement an example in my code

Comment: This works in case there is only one @ as you mentioned, but I need it to look for the last @ sign in the text

Comment: What would be the solution if I need the latest occurrence ?

Comment: @Zash__ Please provide an example input and expected output

Comment: i have now added the example

Comment: index: Index(_base: Swift.String.UnicodeScalarView.Index(_position: 7), _countUTF16: 1)
how can I work with this? thats what the print statement gives me

Comment: @Zash__ Again, what output do you want for this input string `"hello @tom @mark @mathias"`? Please just write the expected output

Comment: Maybe to make it more clear: Just like in Instagram and fb you can link users by writing an @ sign and all users you can link appear, I want to build this feature.

Comment: @Zash__This is very different from the topic of your original question. You should create a new question and describe the new problem.

Comment: No the linking works, its just that the text is shown correctly and if I have the correct solution the problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

```
let text = "hello, how are you @tom?"
let trimSpot = text.index(of: "@") ?? text.endIndex
let trimmed = text[..<trimSpot]
```

Since a string is a collection of Character type, it can be accessed as such. The second line finds the index of the @ sign and assigns its value to trimSpot, but if it is not there, the endIndex of the string is assigned through the use of the nil coalescing operator

```
    ??
```

The string, or collection of Characters, can be provided a range that will tell it what characters to get. The expression inside of the brackets,

```
    ..<trimSpot
```

is a range from 0 to trimSpot-1. So,

```
    text[..<trimSpot]
```

returns an instance of type Substring, which points at the original String instance.

Comment: index(of:) is not a valid method of a String data type

Comment: I see. I am playgrounding in Swift 3.1 so it didn't give me that option.

Comment: its swift 4 sorry, i always use swift 3 because otherwhise i get no reply^^

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This does not solve my problem as I only want to replace the string behind the latest @ sign with the cell.nameLabel. When I write @to and press on the cell with he label tomas it should change the text to @ tomas. And then I should be able to continue and link more users @ lo and press on the cell with the name Lola it should be @ lola -> "@ tomas @ lola".  (without the space but I can't send it without space between @ sign and username somehow here on stack)

Comment: @Zash__ you can find the index on the reversed string like `text.reversed().index(of: "@")` then subtract it from the length of the string

Answer (score 1):

Try regular expressions, they are much safer (if you know what you are doing...)

```
  let hello2 = "hello, how are you @tom, @my @next @victim?"

    let deletedStringsAfterAtSign = hello2.replacingOccurrences(of: "@\\w+", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

    print(deletedStringsAfterAtSign)
    //prints "hello, how are you ,   ?"
```

And this code removes exactly what you need and leaves the characters after the strings clear, so you can see the , and ? still being there. :)

EDIT: what you asked in comments to this answer:

```
  let hello2 = "hello, how are you @tom, @my @next @victim?"

  if let elementIwannaAfterEveryAtSign = hello2.components(separatedBy: " @").last
  {
    let deletedStringsAfterAtSign = hello2.replacingOccurrences(of: "@\\w+", with: elementIwannaAfterEveryAtSign, options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    print(deletedStringsAfterAtSign)
    //prints hello, how are you victim?, victim? victim? victim??
    }
```

Comment: I need exactly this but only for the latest @ sign, currently it replaces everything with the same input "@ mark @ Thomas @ Marie"  becomes-> " @ Marie @ Marie @ Marie"

Comment: Try the edit in my answer... if you wanna the at sign before the victim, add : 

`replacingOccurrences(of: "@\\w+", with: "@\(elementIwannaAfterEveryAtSign)", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)`